# Very simple question about tensor product of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I'm sure that this is a silly question, however I couldn't find any clarify on the internet. Take two copies of the $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathbb Z$ (i.e. of $\mathbb Z$ as abelian group) and consider their tensor product. We have that $M:=\mathbb Z \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Z$ is again a $\mathbb Z$-module, so an abelian group. I have some problems in identifying the equivalence class of $0_M$: in fact, one has that $$(0,1)=(0\cdot 0,1)\sim(0,0\cdot1)=(0,0),$$ and similarly $(1,0)\sim (0,0)$. I'm thinking a couple $(a,b)$ as an element of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ and the dot indicates the product in both modules (that actually is the usual product in $\mathbb Z$). However the contradiction is that $(0,1)+(1,0)=(1,1)$, that is not  in the equivalence class of $0_M$. What am I missing? Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you know that it is a simple question?

Comment: Because it follows directly from the definitions, so anyone with some practice of modules should have the answer bright clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confusing tensor products with usual products (which are the same as sums) of two modules. An element of $M\otimes M$ is **not** a pair of elements of $M$, but an equivalence class of the free module with $M \times M$ as a free basis.

In the tensor product, $0_\mathbb Z \otimes 1_\mathbb Z = 1_\mathbb Z\otimes 0_\mathbb Z = 0_{\mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Z}$ is just the zero element. However, $1_\mathbb Z \otimes 1_\mathbb Z$ is distinct from zero.

Note that in the tensor product addition is **not** pairwise, i.e. $a \otimes b + c \otimes d \neq (a + c) \otimes (b + d)$. Rather, $a \otimes b + c \otimes d$ is just some element of the tensor product. What is true is that e.g. $a \otimes c + b \otimes c = (a + b) \otimes c$, so $\otimes$ behaves much like multiplication.